# How to check row if value exists php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

So the first time I run it, the output was data added, and second time I run it the output was data exists, how if I change value into 888 and 999 but it still insert into table? because in the future the value will back to 123 and 456. thank you, and I appreciate if anyone corrects my question

```
<?php 
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'database') or die('Error connecting to MySQL server');

$check=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT col1, col2 FROM mytable");
$checkrows=mysqli_num_rows($check);

if ($checkrows > 0) 
{
    echo "<br>data exists";
}
else
{  
  $sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (`col1`, `col2`) VALUES ('123', '456')";
  $conn->query($sql);
  echo "<br>data added";
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't see the values `888` and `999` appearing anywhere in your code.  I don't understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i mean if values from $sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (`col1`, `col2`) VALUES ('123', '456')"; i change into 888 and 999 but it can insert it into table

Comment: in database: table is auto-increment or not? show your table structure

Comment: @BilalAhmed yes it is auto-increment

Answer (score 0):

In you’re $check variable where you make the query too see if the data is already written you’re missing the WHERE element, after FROM my table, you need to add WHERE col1 = ‘888’ AND col2 = ‘999’

Answer (score 0):

If you have added 123 and 456 in the first time, and now you want to add 888 and 999 do the following.

```
<?php 
$col1 = 888;
$col2 = 999;

$conn = mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'root', '', 'database') or die('Error connecting to MySQL server' );
$sql_query = " SELECT col1, col2 FROM mytable where ( col1 = $col1 and col2 = $col2 )"
$check = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql_query );

$checkrows = mysqli_num_rows( $check );

if ( $checkrows > 0 ) {

    echo "<br>data exists";

} else {

    $sql = " INSERT INTO mytable ( `col1`, `col2` ) VALUES ( $col1, $col2 )";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql );
    echo "<br> data added ";
}
?>
```